# Colab Error: cannot import name '_NUMEXPR_INSTALLED'

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab and trying to use PyLDAvis to visualize a topic modelling model made from gensim. The python code was working fine but has suddenly started to give me the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_NUMEXPR_INSTALLED' from 'pandas.core.computation.check' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/check.py)
```

The error comes from the line `from pandas.core.computation.check import NUMEXPR_INSTALLED` in the file `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/eval.py`. I believe this line is being called by `pyLDAvis.gensim_models.prepare`.

I tried putting `!pip install numexpr` but it doesn't get rid of the error. What is surprising is that when I call `!pip install numexpr`, the output is:

```
Requirement already satisfied: numexpr in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from numexpr) (1.20.2)
```

which means that numexpr can be found in `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages`

Comment: The current version of pandas has `NUMEXPR_INSTALLED`, but not `_NUMEXPR_INSTALLED`.  Can you double-check your "eval.py" and "check.py" and make sure they match?

Comment: You may need to upgrade pandas in Colab.  PyLDAvis requires >= [1.2](https://github.com/bmabey/pyLDAvis/blob/master/requirements.txt), while Colab's installed version is 1.1.5.  So try `!pip install --upgrade pandas`.

Comment: @TimRoberts any idea how to do that in Google Colab?

Comment: @AlexK that didn't work

Comment: @AvinashKumar in response to your question to @TimRoberts, in Colab you can use Unix commands to work with files: `!cat /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/check.py` will print the contents of `check.py`.

Comment: Turned out to be a mistake from my side.... I had missed that Colab was asking me to restart the runtime which I had not done.

Answer (score 1):

@AlexK's answer worked for me. I just had to specify which version of pandas to use in order for Colab to actually upgrade with:

```
!pip install --upgrade pandas==1.2
```